# Remove data from sub list

Tags: c#, list

I created this sample project where I am trying to remove sub data using the `Where` and `Any` but it still contains the data. It should remove the DD notes and just keep the CC notes.

Any help on this would be great.

```
TemplateNote = TemplateNote.Where(x =>
    x.Content == "AA" &&
    x.Conditions.Any(v => v.Target != removeAgentDisease)
).ToList();
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/a3d6Py

current Output includes the DD notes

```
TemplateNote AA
TemplateNoteCondition CC
TemplateNoteCondition DD
```

Should be this without the DD

```
TemplateNote AA
TemplateNoteCondition CC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing from the parent list, not from the child list. Therefore you have to create a copy-`TemplateNoteModel` with a new child-list that just contains the desired items:

```
TemplateNote = TemplateNote
    .Select(tn => new TemplateNoteModel
    {
        Conditions = tn.Conditions
           .Where(c => c.Target != removeAgentDisease)
           .ToList(),
        Content = tn.Content,
        Id = tn.Id
    })
    .Where(x => x.Conditions.Any()) // i guess you don't want empty condtions
    .ToList();
```

Your modified fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yduh5o

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without creating a copy-TemplateNoteModel?

Comment: @Jefferson: Yes, you need to use a loop over `TemplateNote` and modify each `TemplateNoteModel` with the query shown in my answer. So instead of `TemplateNote=TemplateNote.Select(...)` you just mofify the `Conditions` property in the loop: `tn.Conditions=tn.Conditions.Where(c => c.Target != removeAgentDisease).ToList();`. So you just re-create the (sub-)list. Keep in mind that you don't remove the empty-Conditions-lists in this approach.

Comment: Sorry what if I also wanted to remove the parent ?

Comment: with the removeAgentDisease-conditions

Comment: If you want to remove all parents which have only removeAgentDisease-conditions and the loop approach you need a second (result-)list that you fill from the loop: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GdrXzB If you MUST keep the original list you could either re-assign the result-list to the original list or you need a second loop where you remove the items from the first list that are NOT in the result list. You can use `list.RemoveAll`

Comment: .... as shown here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XVPTck